Exercise on Segre subvariety as zero locus of a bihomogeneous polynomial
Exercise from my class in algebraic geometry.
Let $\varphi: \mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^3, \ \varphi([x_0:x_1])=[x_0^4:x_0^3x_1:x_0x_1^3:x_1^4]$ and $C=\varphi(\mathbb{P}^1)$.
I was able to prove that $C \subset \Sigma_{1,1}$. Now I have to prove that $C$ as subvariety of $\Sigma_{1,1}$ is equal to the zero locus of a bihomogeneous polynomial of bedegree $(1,3)$. I tried to find some homogeneous polynomial of degree $3$ that vanishes on $C$ but I didn't conclude anything.
Any help?

Hint.
Take
$$
\phi_1(x_0:x_1) = (x_0:x_1),
\qquad
\phi_2(x_0:x_1) = (x_0^3:x_1^3),
$$
and consider the composition
$$
\mathbb{P}^1 \to 
\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \to 
\mathbb{P}^3,
$$
where the first map is $(\phi_1,\phi_2)$ and the second is the Segre emebdding.

Thank you for the hint
